# bash: What is the difference between these two script variants?

Tags: bash, shell-script, find, gnu

(Note: Both of these examples *may* require GNU or BSD `find` and may not work as-is with the POSIX "edition" of `find`).

Both of the scriptlets below must be understood as *excerpts* from way more complex scripts, with the gist having been compacted into a few lines.
As I get the *exact same* results with both variants, I'm wondering where the differences (respectively: pitfalls) of either implementation may be...

- var. 1

```
while IFS= read -r f; do

  echo "reading entry: "$f""

done < <(find ~/workdocs -type f -name '*.pdf' -print)
```

- var. 2

```
while IFS= read -rd '' f; do

  echo "reading entry: "$f""

done < <(find ~/workdocs -type f -name '*.pdf' -print0)
```

It turned out that the **output** (which this question is all about here) was entirely **identical** in both cases. (Tested by redirecting to output log file, then `diff`'ing both)
Still, I am wondering if there might be any *borderline cases* which may actually cause the outputs from variant #1 and #2 to differ.

This is what I'd like to know about.

Comment: The later handles filenames that contain a newline character.

Comment: Oh thanks! (In fact you've already given the answer.) Most likely I will come across those only once in a blue moon (if at all), but who knows...At least I know I was right calling them "borderline cases", for in normal standard use, none of both would be causing (virtually) any problems...

Comment: The `echo` quoting is nonsense though: `echo "reading entry: "$f""`

Comment: I think it's a habit of mine, because I frequently found I "lost" parts of filenames due to whitespace in the past (i. e. found after a short debug run of the script)

Comment: I didn't mean "nonsense" as "unnecessary". I meant it as nonsense. You should really understand what you have done there. It is a good general rule to quote everything in order to minimize the risk of forgetting to quote.

Comment: @jordanm And how are these filenames separated?

Comment: @HaukeLaging ??? Now you're getting more and more entangled in the spiderweb of contradictions. You said it's nonsense, __clearly__, but then you applaud anyone to obey the "good general rule" of quoting everything to be on the safe shore? Please make up your mind, once and for all, before you call something "nonsense." And FFS, express yourself *clearly* and not so confusing like a philosopher, trying to explain the (highly subjective!!) subtle difference between "nonsense" and "unnecessary". WTH! What's next? The HL theorem about the difference between "rubbish" and "crap"?

Comment: @syntaxerror There is no contradiction. It is OK to always quote. The point is that in `echo "reading entry: "$f""` the relevant part `$f` isn't quoted at all. It is nonsense, **how** the quotes are used in that command; not that they are used.

Comment: Aha, and why didn't you tell that in the first place? Sheesh...You're feeling like a true maths guy, I even knew one personally...same thing.---But that aside, thanks for clearing things up once and for all. Still, it *IS* quoted. Unless someone really proves me wrong, you __may__ nest quotes with `echo` that way. I begin to understand: you read it as first quote ending __before__ `$f` and second (empty) quote starting __after__ `$f`, which leaves the lone `$f` unquoted. I always thought that the way I wrote them, they're interpreted as __nested__. Would need a proof though to think otherwise.

Comment: `echo "reading entry: "$f""` -- the variable is NOT quoted. You're echoing the concatenation of 3 strings: `"reading entry: "`, the unquoted `$f` and then an empty string `""`. You want to put the variable inside quotes: `echo "reading entry: $f"`

Comment: @glenn jackman Yes, this is what I've figured out. But it obviously did require me to "study" Hauke's post first to get me bumped head-first onto the truth...Again, I just could not determine what it stood for, whether it was quotes-inside-quotes or, as I know now, an unquoting technique, actively and deliberately *excluding* the stuff between the quote *pairs*. It was simply a wrong understanding of things...but the main reason was it always __worked__, i. e. no complaints from `bash`'s side. And once it works, you commonly don't start asking about any further hows and whys. :)

Comment: [ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/) can find problems like this. See what comments it generates for `f="this is a string";echo "reading entry: "$f""`. I see where you're coming from re: nested quoting, OTOH, it's not easy for any language to parse nested quotes, since open quotes are identical to close quotes. And with something like bash which concatenates adjacent strings it's impossible to always do so unambiguously.

Comment: FWIW, Hauke Laging didn't mean to be insulting when he said "The echo quoting is nonsense" - he meant that it doesn't make sense, or at least, it doesn't mean what you think it does. You may find the BashGuide articles on [Word Splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting) and [Quotes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) helpful.

Comment: @PM2Ring Many thanks. There is nothing worse I can think of than `bash`'s "error handler" whenever you mistype something (or "inject" something else from other programming languages because you mixed things up again). Those error messages are about as useful as those from several products made by the huge company with the capital M, and in 95% of cases, they will always lead you up the garden path.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of comprehensibility and visibility I abuse an answer for explaining the quoting part. May the SE karma forgive me...

This is (depending on the content of `f`) a special case, the problem is not easy to see:

```
> f=foo
> set -x
> echo "reading entry: "$f""
+ echo 'reading entry: foo'
reading entry: foo
```

The shells debug modus shows just one string. But that is **not** due to "nested quoting".

A change in the variable content or a change of the command line shows the problem:

```
> f=foo

> set -x

> echo "reading entry: " $f ""
+ echo 'reading entry: ' foo ''
reading entry: foo

> echo "reading entry: "    $f     ""
+ echo 'reading entry: ' foo ''
reading entry: foo

> f="foo    bar"
+ echo 'reading entry: foo' bar
reading entry: foo bar
```

If this kind of quoting worked then the spaces would be preserved.

Comment: Thanks for "abusing" (?) this answer! As said in my comments, it was a *long-time* false interpretation of yours truly of this quoting stuff. Well, of course I knew that in JavaScript (simple) nested quoting is achieved by using single quotes for the outer and double ones for the inner term. BUT I knew as well that with `echo` the use of single/double quotes had a totally different __meaning__ (i. e. interpreting `$`... variables and other things (y/n)). So I *assumed* the `bash` way (e. g. echo) is to use double quotes *twice*. However, had I had a notion of how this is interpreted...oh well.

Comment: @syntaxerror It's "abuse" because this answer does not refer to the question... I am not familiar enough with Javascript but single and double quotes (or backslashes) can be combined in bash, too: `echo "The file '${file}' is empty."` That is not the same like `echo 'The file "${file}" is empty.'`

Comment: Yes, that's what I was just trying to point out. In JS, the choice of quotes (single/double) does __not__ change the meaning. But in `bash`, it will, with usually entirely different results in resolving variables (getting literal `$var` output instead of their value) etc...